# How to dynamically reference an array using a string generated by concatenating two dynamic strings?

Tags: c, arrays, string, dynamic, char

I'm trying to randomly pick a character from an array, concatenate it to the string `"array_"` and then use the new string to reference an array.

For instance, pick the character `'8'` from `temp_holder[]`, concatenate it to `"array_"`, and use it to reference `array_8[][]`.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
   int i, j;

   char array_8[5][4];
   //Array
   for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
          array_8[i][j] = 'x';
          if ((i == 1 && j == 1) || (i == 1 && j == 2) || (i == 3 && j == 1) || (i == 3 && j == 2) ){
             array_8[i][j] = ' ';
          }
      }
  }


  char myArray[5][4];
  //Array
   for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
          myArray[i][j] = 'x';
          if ((i == 1 && j == 1) || (i == 1 && j == 2) || (i == 3 && j == 1) || (i == 3 && j == 2) ){
             myArray[i][j] = ' ';
          }
      }
  }

  char temp_holder[6] = {'8', '8', '8', '8', '8'};
  srand(time(NULL));
  int r = rand() % 6; 

  char arrName[1][10] = {"array_"}; 
  char namesArr[10];
  strcpy(namesArr, "array_");
  int len = 7;
  char arr_names[5][4];
  printf("\n%c\n", temp_holder[r]);
  strcat(namesArr, &temp_holder[r]);
  printf("\n%s\n", namesArr);
  strncpy(arr_names, namesArr, len);
  strcat(arr_names, "\0"); 
  printf("\n%s\n", arr_names);


  int accEntry = 0; //Correct entry counter
  for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
      for (j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
       if (myArray[i][j] == arr_names[i][j]){
          printf("\n MATCH FOUND  %c\n", arr_names[i][j]);
          accEntry++;
       }
   } 

   printf("\n\n\n%d\n\n\n", accEntry);

   getchar();
}
```

Comment: Variable names are for the programmer, not for the program.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you create your own name to array lookup table, you can't do what you are trying to do. Assuming you have a POSIX system, you can refer to global symbols by name, but you have to use `dlopen`/`dlsym` to do so. If the variable or function name is not coming from a shared library, then you have to link the program with `-rdynamic` when compiling with GCC, or whatever the equivalent is for your system.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

char array_8[][10] = { "hello", "world" };

int main ()
{
    void *h = dlopen(0, RTLD_NOW);
    void *p = dlsym(h, "array_8");
    assert(p == array_8);
    dlclose(h);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> For instance, pick the character "8", from `temp_holder[]`, concatenate
>   it to "array_" and use it to reference `array_8[][]`

You can't do that in C. The names of the variables are meaningless at runtime, i.e. you can't "get a variable by name".

Answer (score 0):

you obviously can't do that. you can use a array of pointers, which can be used to hold the references to your arrays.

Comment: Your solution seems most plausible to me since i'm not that good at C. If you could show me an example of your solution, that would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table to store pointers to the arrays, that way you can access them by name.